# loss of theme options while site deployment in production

Tags: themes, options, deployment

i have moved both wordpress folder and the development database on a distant server.
Why all my theme options are lost ? 
where are these options stored if not in wp_options table nor wp_files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this has something to do with data serialization and the fact that i have search and replace on my entire database to change the URLs,

see the "When Your Domain Name or URLs Change" section of

```
     http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress
```

Comment: You didn't see the notes in the Codex listed under: "To avoid that serialization issue, ..."

Comment: yes i did but i did not know how to solve it practically.i then used the wp migrate DB plugin